# Logarithmic Relationship for Chart in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, java

In the below code, how can I compute logarithmic trendlines? Google Earth Engine just computes `linear`, `exponential` and `polynomial` automatically. In other words I need slope and offset values in logarithmic relationship between two variables(data1 and data2).

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3529165c811530af1169747d68983ffa

```
var data1 = ee.List([1,2,3,4]);
var data2 = ee.List([10,100,1000,10000]);


var data1Array = ee.Array(data1);
var data2Array = ee.Array(data2);


var log_chart = ui.Chart.array.values(data1Array,0,data2Array).setOptions({
      title: 'logarithmic Curve',
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 3,
      trendlines: { 0: {
          type: 'linear',   //exponential, linear, polynomial
          color: 'red',
          lineWidth: 3,
          opacity: 10,
          showR2: true,
          visibleInLegend: true
      }}
});


print(log_chart);
```